# How to show images in subfolder pages (pages are in PHP)

Tags: php, html, css, image, include

Basically I have a website that I want to put resources and tutorials and whatever else on and I figured in order to do this so its somewhat more organized I'll create some folders. For the sake of this question I'll keep it simple.

On my desktop I have my website folder, which has all my main pages (Index, about, etc.) I have a folder called "Includes" which consists of my header, footer, nav and sidebar. Then I also have a content folder, and inside that is all my main content pages (blends, film reviews, tumblr tutorials, etc.)

Now, I've figured out how to get the CSS to show in these subfolders but my layout image and my social icons in my footer are not showing up in these subfolder pages..

My layout image is in a folder called "homepage" inside a folder called "Images" inside my main folder(the one with EVERYTHING inside) and the social icons are in the same folder, but in another folder called "social icons"

The header.php file located in the includes folder is where my layout image code is. This is the code I'm using to call the header.php file in these subfolders (ex. /content/blends.php)

```
 <?php 
 $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
 $path .= "/includes/header.php";
 include_once($path);
?>
```

Now I do understand why it's not working, or I think I do anyways, because I think it would be looking in the includes folder for the images.

This is also the code I'm using for my footer

```
<?php include('../includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

So essentially, if I'm correct about why it's not working, my question is, how do I get them to show?

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: My website is www.temnota.co.uk if you wanted to look at my source code or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the full path.

If your structure is as following:

```
ROOT
   - index.php
   - includes/
   - some_other_folder/
   - images/
```

When you include a file from the index.php, all you need is:

```
include("includes/header.php");
```

When you want to include it from some_other_folder:

```
include("../includes/header.php");
```

Also - consider using [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) instead.

**EDIT**:
Per your comment, I looked at your website and inspected the footer, there doesn't seem to be any `<img>` tag in it at all.

I may be stating the obvious but - `Include` is designed to include .php files.
From the .php files you need to echo `<img>` tags for your images to show.

**Also remember** if your file is located at `include/footer.php` and you are including it from `index.php`, ALL IMAGE PATHS MUST BE RELATIVE TO THE MAIN FILE (index.php), NOT THE INCLUDED FILE (footer.php), because it is executed in the context of the main file that included it.

So in this case, an `<img>` tag located in footer.php, should look like that:

`<img src='images/footer.jpg'>`.

AND NOT

`<img src='../images/footer.jpg'>`.

This is different than your CSS files, where you put the path of an image relative to the CSS file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't seem to work. This is the best way I can explain my structure. 
http://i61.tinypic.com/2n6dpjm.png